# Cannot load model in python when run as NodeJs child process

Tags: python, node.js, keras, tensorflow2.0, child-process

When I run the python program standalone, I get the output. But when run as a child process in NodeJS I get model doesn't exist error.

Correct output when run standalone:
[image]

Error I piped to text file when run as child process:
[image]
[image]

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: I'm wondering if the python program relies on a current working directory that isn't correctly set when you run it as a child process from node.js.  There is an option with spawn to pass it the current working directory you want set for the new process.  Or, you could change the python program not to depend upon the current working directory.

Comment: In the future, please post code as text, not as images.  If/when people are trying to test your code or write answers, you want them to be able to copy/paste your code, not have to manually retype it all.  It's also best if the code is indexed for searching.

Comment: Hey @jfriend00! Upon seeing your suggestion, I passed the CWD as {cwd:'../Final Generator'} and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: I'll keep in mind to post code hereon @jfriend00, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If the python program relies on a current working directory that isn't correctly set when you run it as a child process from node.js, then it may not find its files properly and that current working directory would likely be different when starting it with `spawn()`.

There is an option with spawn to pass it the current working directory you want set for the new process. Or, you could change the python program not to depend upon the current working directory.